# Theming in Android - Eclipse

Tags: android

So I am editing a go launcher template theme and i saw there were some parts i wanted to change that wasn't included in the template. For example the little icons on top of the apps when you want to delete (kill.png kill_light.png etc.) I added this code

```
<AppIcon text_color="#FFFFFFFF" text_bg_color="#ff3f3f3f" delete_app="kill"         
delete_app_highlight="kill_light" new_app_icon="new_install_app"   
update_icon="appfunc_app_update" locker_icon="promanage_lock_icon" 
close_app_icon="promanage_close_normal" close_app_light="promanage_close_light"/>
```

With png's with the right names in the drawable hdpi folder but they don't show up when I test it out. Am I missing something? I was able change the media management icons in the app drawer by adding this

```
<SwitchButtonBean button_galleryicon="appfunc_mediamanagement_switch _button_gallery"   
button_gallerylighticon="appfunc_mediamanagement_s witch_button_gallery_light" 
button_musicicon="appfunc_mediamanagement_switch_b utton_music"          
button_musiclighticon="appfunc_mediamanagement_swi tch_button_music_light" 
button_videoicon="appfunc_mediamanagement_switch_b utton_video"   
button_videolighticon="appfunc_mediamanagement_swi tch_button_video_light" 
button_appicon="appfunc_mediamanagement_switch_but ton_app"    
button_appiconlight="appfunc_mediamanagement_switc h_button_app_light"/>
```

But it didn't work for the other part (the smaller versions of those same icons in the media management menu).
What am I missing?